# How to trigger Boostrap Alert from a C# try catch block

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have a Razor Page in AspNet Core 3.1 on which I am able to click a button and a Bootstrap alert will appear.  Here is the jquery - which works fine:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(showError);

        $('#linkClose').click(function () {
            $('#errorAlert').hide('fade');
        });
    });

    function showError() {
            $('#errorAlert').show('fade');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#errorAlert').hide('fade');
            }, 5000);
    }

    if (@Model.ShowError) {
        showError();
    }
</script>
```

What I would like to do is be able to is to trigger that same alert from the "code-behind" from a try catch block after I have logged the error:

Here's where I want to do that:

```
[TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public bool ShowError { get; set; } = false;
```

public async Task OnGetAsync(bool id)
        {
            ShowError =id;

```
        try
        {
            var ret = ManipulateMyFile(file)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("File being used - {ex}", ex);
            ErrorMessage= "File being used";

            return Redirect("/Admin/LearningTasks/Index/true");
        }
        return Redirect("/Admin/LearningTasks/Index/false");
    }
```

Any help in achieving this greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to return script tags from c# code? what is the use case that you are trying to fix with this?

Comment: Is your call to server side via post or ajax?

Comment: I want to return script tags from c# code because the error information that I am logging is generated on the server side.  I want to show the information client-side as a popup.

Comment: I am using Razor Pages with .Net Core 3.1  (razor pages, not mvc).  The call to the server is via a post and is found in the cshtml.cs page under OnPostAsync().

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in the ViewBag, and then check it in the view to trigger the javascript function. If you do this though, make sure you set it to `false` as a default or it could result in an error in the view.

In the controller

```
ViewBag.ShowError = false;

try 
{
    var ret = ManipulateMyFile(file)
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Log.Error("File being used - {ex}", ex);
    ViewBag.ShowError = true;
}
```

And then in the Razor view

```
<script>
    var doShowError = @ViewBag.ShowError.ToString().ToLower();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(showError);

        $('#linkClose').click(function () {
            $('#errorAlert').hide('fade');
        });

        // show the error
        if (doShowError) {
            showError();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I have taken suggestions by @chrisbyte and edited code snippets in original post to reflect that I am not using mvc model but pure razor pages - however still having problems.  Also, would like to get away from full page refresh that my approach results in.